# Cannot request full screen again chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, fullscreen

I have a problem. Full screen request works good in Firefox, but in Chrome when I request and cancel full screen, I can't request it again (F11 works). Moreover when I reload the page it cancel full screen.

```
jQuery('.fullScreen').click(function(){ 
   var docElm = document.documentElement;

   if (docElm.requestFullscreen) {
      docElm.requestFullscreen();
   }

   else if (docElm.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      docElm.mozRequestFullScreen();          
   }

   else if (docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
      docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen(); 
}   
      jQuery('.fullScreen').css({'display' : 'none'});
      jQuery('.minimize').css({'display' : 'block'});
   });
```

Minimize:

```
jQuery('.minimize').click(function(){               

                            if (document.exitFullscreen) {
                            document.exitFullscreen();
                            }

                            else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
                                document.mozCancelFullScreen();
                            }

                            else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
                                document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
                            }               

                        jQuery('.fullScreen').css({'display' : 'block'});
                        jQuery('.minimize').css({'display' : 'none'});
                });
```

Moreover, when I press esc in full screen, it minimize, but I can't back to full screen using my button.

Comment: It's work properly in my Chrome (v 20). Can you get more information about browser version and how your implement minimize (if you not exit by F11)?

Comment: I've added this function in the first post. I'm using Chrome v22.0.1229.94 m.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok so a couple of ideas.

firstly the reason why it doesn't work when you press the escape button. is very simply because your jquery is not being executed. to solve the refresh issue you can place a cookie stating weather the browser is in full screen or not and if it is you can make it full screen on the page ready event. i would like to propose a new idea for you

below is a fully copy pasteable demo of the full screen api

i would like to highlight a snippet

```
    fsElement.addEventListener(fullScreenApi.fullScreenEventName, function() {
    if (fullScreenApi.isFullScreen()) {
        fsStatus.innerHTML = 'Whoa, you went fullscreen';
    } else {
        fsStatus.innerHTML = 'Back to normal';
    }
}, true);
```

you can add code in this event to handle when the user leaves full screen mode. and just run your minimize methhod

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
            <title>FullScreen API</title>

            <style>
            body {
                background: #F3F5FA;
            }
            #container {
                width: 600px;
                padding: 30px;
                background: #F8F8F8;
                border: solid 1px #ccc;
                color: #111;
                margin: 20px auto;
                border-radius: 3px;
            }

            #specialstuff {
                background: #33e;
                padding: 20px;
                margin: 20px;
                color: #fff;
            }
            #specialstuff a {
                color: #eee;
            }

            #fsstatus {
                background: #e33;
                color: #111;
            }

            #fsstatus.fullScreenSupported {
                background: #3e3;
            }
            </style>
            </head>
            <body>
            <div id="container">
                <div id="specialstuff">
                    <p>Inside here is special stuff which will go fullscreen</p>
                    <p>As of 10/20/2011, you'll need Safari 5.1, <a href="http://tools.google.com/dlpage/chromesxs">Chrome Canary</a>, or <a href="http://nightly.mozilla.org/">Firefox Nightly</a>
                    <p>Status: <span id="fsstatus"></span>
                </div>

                <input type="button" value="Go Fullscreen" id="fsbutton" />
                <p>
                </p>
            </div>


            <script>

            (function() {
            var 
                fullScreenApi = { 
                    supportsFullScreen: false,
                    isFullScreen: function() { return false; }, 
                    requestFullScreen: function() {}, 
                    cancelFullScreen: function() {},
                    fullScreenEventName: '',
                    prefix: ''
                },
                browserPrefixes = 'webkit moz o ms khtml'.split(' ');

            // check for native support
            if (typeof document.cancelFullScreen != 'undefined') {
                fullScreenApi.supportsFullScreen = true;
            } else {     
                // check for fullscreen support by vendor prefix
                for (var i = 0, il = browserPrefixes.length; i < il; i++ ) {
                    fullScreenApi.prefix = browserPrefixes[i];

                    if (typeof document[fullScreenApi.prefix + 'CancelFullScreen' ] != 'undefined' ) {
                        fullScreenApi.supportsFullScreen = true;

                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            // update methods to do something useful
            if (fullScreenApi.supportsFullScreen) {
                fullScreenApi.fullScreenEventName = fullScreenApi.prefix + 'fullscreenchange';

                fullScreenApi.isFullScreen = function() {
                    switch (this.prefix) {  
                        case '':
                            return document.fullScreen;
                        case 'webkit':
                            return document.webkitIsFullScreen;
                        default:
                            return document[this.prefix + 'FullScreen'];
                    }
                }
                fullScreenApi.requestFullScreen = function(el) {
                    return (this.prefix === '') ? el.requestFullScreen() : el[this.prefix + 'RequestFullScreen']();
                }
                fullScreenApi.cancelFullScreen = function(el) {
                    return (this.prefix === '') ? document.cancelFullScreen() : document[this.prefix + 'CancelFullScreen']();
                }       
            }

            // jQuery plugin
            if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {
                jQuery.fn.requestFullScreen = function() {

                    return this.each(function() {
                        var el = jQuery(this);
                        if (fullScreenApi.supportsFullScreen) {
                            fullScreenApi.requestFullScreen(el);
                        }
                    });
                };
            }

            // export api
            window.fullScreenApi = fullScreenApi;   
            })();

            </script>

            <script>

            // do something interesting with fullscreen support
            var fsButton = document.getElementById('fsbutton'),
            fsElement = document.getElementById('specialstuff'),
            fsStatus = document.getElementById('fsstatus');


            if (window.fullScreenApi.supportsFullScreen) {
            fsStatus.innerHTML = 'YES: Your browser supports FullScreen';
            fsStatus.className = 'fullScreenSupported';

            // handle button click
            fsButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
                window.fullScreenApi.requestFullScreen(fsElement);
            }, true);

            fsElement.addEventListener(fullScreenApi.fullScreenEventName, function() {
                if (fullScreenApi.isFullScreen()) {
                    fsStatus.innerHTML = 'Whoa, you went fullscreen';
                } else {
                    fsStatus.innerHTML = 'Back to normal';
                }
            }, true);

            } else {
            fsStatus.innerHTML = 'SORRY: Your browser does not support FullScreen';
            }

            </script>

            </body>
            </html>
```

below i have a updated version of your jquery

```
jQuery('.fullScreen').click(function(){ 
    maximize();
});

jQuery('.minimize').click(function(){               
    minimize();
});





function maximize(){
    var docElm = document.documentElement;

    if (docElm.requestFullscreen) {
    docElm.requestFullscreen();
    }

    else if (docElm.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    docElm.mozRequestFullScreen();          
    }

    else if (docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
    docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen(); 
    }   
    jQuery('.fullScreen').css({'display' : 'none'});
    jQuery('.minimize').css({'display' : 'block'});
}

function minimize(){
    if (document.exitFullscreen) {
    document.exitFullscreen();
    }

    else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
    document.mozCancelFullScreen();
    }

    else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
    document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
    }               

    jQuery('.fullScreen').css({'display' : 'block'});
    jQuery('.minimize').css({'display' : 'none'});
}
```

an importent note

FullScreenChanged event – The W3C and Webkit fire the fullscreenchanged event on the element going fullscreen, but Mozilla fires the event on the document object.

Comment: The spec has changed. `webkitCancelFullScreen` is now `webkitExitFullscreen`.
http://generatedcontent.org/post/70347573294/is-your-fullscreen-api-code-up-to-date-find-out-how-to